# How to set SQLite isolation levels in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions, isolation-level

I know that in the SQL standard there are four isolation levels when dealing with transactions:

```
READ UNCOMMITTED - will allow everything
READ COMMITTED - will not allow dirty reads 
REPEATABLE READ - will not allow dirty, non-repearable reads   
SERIALIZABLE - will not allow dirty, non-repearable, phantom reads
```

When dealing with MySQL I can do something like:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED")
```

Or, if I'm dealing with Postgresql, I can do something like:

```
db.set_isolation_level(3) # corresponds to SERIALIZABLE
```

So, I wonder, if I can do something similar to that when dealing with `SQLite`.

I've only seen the following but I'm not sure what it means and how I can set other isolation levels (if they exist in the context of `SQLite`)

```
db.isolation_level = None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [PRAGMA statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) in sqlite. It seems you can do this:

```
db.execute("PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true;");
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I only want to clarify one tiny thing - does sqlite support all isolation levels? So, will your example work for `read_commited`, `repeatable read` and `serializable`?

Comment: @Jacobian All transactions in SQLite are `SERIALIZABLE`, unless they are using a shared cache and have `read_uncommitted` set to true as Martin notes.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Martin's answer...

All transaction in SQLite are `SERIALIZABLE`, because SQLite controls concurrency via a database-wide read-write lock, so that there can only be one writer at a time.

The exception to this is if you have set up [shared cache mode](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) between two or more connections in the same process and enabled [the `read_uncommited` pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_read_uncommitted), in which case those connections can operate in `READ UNCOMMITED` mode (but connections outside of the shared cache will block them as usual).

Comment: Thank you, sir! But I still do not get one little thing. Does it mean that in order to have truly serizalizable transactions in SQLite using Python, I do not have to do anything like `db.isolation_level = None` and `db.execute("PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true;")`? Simple `cursor.execute("begin")`, `cursor.execute(command_1)`, `cursor.execute("command_2")`, `cursor.execute("commit")` will be enough?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation SQLite supports [WAL Mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (in fact, `SNAPSHOT` isolation level).

See details about [isolation in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html).